Updating certificate on scaled environment causes analytics error "The certificate was not found."
Sitecore 10.3 with SXA 10.3 - Wildcard Certificate Issue with Analytics
I’m running a scaled setup on Sitecore 10.3, where:

CM server has 4 xConnect roles.
2 CD servers.
A separate server for the remaining xConnect roles.

Our wildcard certificate recently expired, so we installed a new one. Here’s what I did:

installed it on all the servers
set the private key permissions
updated the IIS bindings on all servers
updated the connectionstrings with the new thumbprint on all roles
restarted IIS on all servers

Everything works fine except Experience Analytics. The following error appears in the CMS logs when accessing the analytics board:
I keep getting the below error in my CMS logs whenever I open the Experience analytics board:

Exception Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: An
error occurred while sending the request. --->
System.InvalidOperationException: The certificate was not found.
Store: My, Location: LocalMachine, FindType: FindByThumbprint,
FindValue: 432352ASAD3F5AESAMDSAO9930249A99DA1, InvalidAllowed: False.

The thumbprint in the error belongs to the expired certificate, which I have already removed from all servers and configurations.
I've already gone through every other question or article I found about this, I have tried so far the below several times:

Double checked all configs and identityserver have new thumbprint
New cert is installed correctly in LocalMachine's "Personal" store
Private key permissions are exactly the same as the old cert
Old cert is removed from all stores, Personal or CA
Restarted IIS, recycled app pools, restarted the xconnect services, restarted the servers themselves

Despite these efforts, the error persists.
Any suggestions or ideas for resolving this would be greatly appreciated!

It looks like you must have just missed updating a thumbrprint somewhere. The best bet would be to search from the root of every application for the old thumbprint 432352ASAD3F5AESAMDSAO9930249A99DA1. I use a program called total commander, which allows recursive searches for strings within files.
The most likely issue is one of the thumbprints within ConnectionStrings.config (on CM) or AppSettings.config (Collection or Collection Search).
Complete list of places to check below:
CM
ConnectionStrings.config

xconnect.collection.certificate
xdb.marketingautomation.operations.client.certificate
xdb.marketingautomation.reporting.client.certificate
xdb.referencedata.client.certificate
xconnect.search.certificate
cortex.processing.engine.certificate

Collection
App_Config/AppSettings.config

validateCertificateThumbprint

Collection Search
App_Config/AppSettings.config

validateCertificateThumbprint

Cortex Processing
App_Config/AppSettings.config

validateCertificateThumbprint

App_Data/jobs/continuous/ProcessingEngine/App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config

xconnect.collection.certificate
xconnect.configuration.certificate
xconnect.search.certificate

Cortex Reporting
App_Config/AppSettings.config

validateCertificateThumbprint

Marketing Automation
App_Config/AppSettings.config

validateCertificateThumbprint

App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config

xconnect.collection.certificate

App_Data/jobs/continuous/AutomationEngine/App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config

xconnect.collection.certificate

Marketing Automation Reporting
App_Config/AppSettings.config

validateCertificateThumbprint

Reference Data
App_Config/AppSettings.config

validateCertificateThumbprint


Hi @Dean, I've been using notepad++ and searched using the old thumbprint in all of the sites' roots, but I cannot find it still anywhere, I searched as well for all strings with "certificate" and made sure they have the new thumbprint, and redid all the restarts, still same issue :/

See updated answer above. The most likely issue is one of the thumbprints within ConnectionStrings.config (on CM) or AppSettings.config (Collection or Collection Search).

Is it possible that this is an upgraded solution and you have a reporting instance still configured? Do you have separate processing role?

Hi @Dean, I can't believe this but I went over the connectionstrings in the CM one more time (like the 20th), and my changes were not saved for some bizarre reason! It showed me the old thumbnail still, even though I searched for it and it would show show me "no results" all night, gonna have trust issues with notepad++ now lol, thanks a lot I fixed it in CM and made sure its saved, analytics working fine now.

No problem, glad its fixed!
